# pycaret.anomaly.compare_models() not working; "no attribute 'compare_models'", "'compare_models' is not defined"

Tags: python, pycaret

I have tried using the compare_models() function for anomaly detection in PyCaret, but it always gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-df60bd5a4f1b> in <module>()
----> 1 compared = pycaret.anomaly.compare_models()

AttributeError: module 'pycaret.anomaly' has no attribute 'compare_models'
```

If I try to do just compare_models():

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-47f60ac858d1> in <module>()
----> 1 compared = compare_models()

NameError: name 'compare_models' is not defined
```

It does this both when run in the terminal and in Google Colab. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it seems that this function is only supported in pycaret.classification and pycaret.regression modules.

More information: https://pycaret.org/compare-models/